# Filling JMeter fields correctly for the simplest WebSocket request

Tags: json, websocket, jmeter, wss

How to fill JMeter's WebSocket Sampler fields correctly to execute a minimal wss-request?

If I fill just server name (path) and then execute test, everything is fine.
But if I add some data to 'Request data' field there is an undefined error.

Where should the JSON-data be placed?

Thanks.

Screens are added.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot connect to the remote server

I would assume that either server is down or your connection details are incorrect, i.e. my expectation is that for `wss` protocol you [should be using port `443`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

You can also add the next line to *user.properties* file to enable debugging output to the *jmeter.log* file

```
log_level.JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket=DEBUG
```

See [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) article for more information on conducting Websocket load testing using JMeter

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using this JMeter websocket plugin:
https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers
Add a "WebSocket resquest-response sampler" to your test plan, add the json as "request data" and off you go.